# how to restrict file access using htaccess file , if user session is not set in php

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am facing problem with following code as my code for htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
# you can add whatever extensions you want routed to your php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(zip)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "pathoffile"/download_file.php [L]

and php code is 

<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
echo "Access Denied";   
}


?>
```

when i click on following link ,
if session exists , should download the file but it is not.

Comment: you can add restriction in download_file.php file itself. On top write your session condition.

Comment: You have rewritten the request to a script file - so that script file is now _completely_ responsibly for what happens after. Your script does not only have to handle the negative case (user not authorized - no download, error message instead), but the positive one as well: Your script needs to read the contents of the file and output them to the browser.

Comment: it also seems to me that using `session_start();`, your `$_SESSION` array will always be set (even if empty) and your test always true. If you create a session somewhere and want to check it here, you should set a var when you create it, and check for this key in the session array

Comment: Can anyone give me hint , that suppose i know the url of any downloaded link, may i able to stop dircet access from URL if user put direct URL for download, then not access , but from project able to do downlaod.
I have tried with session system but not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all your file requests to a download_file.php?with=filename, then you can validate user section from there.